How to use qwt 6-3.0 with cmake
I am trying to use Qwt 6-3.0 with Qt 6.7.0 on Kubuntu 24.04, using KDevelop 5.12.23 and cmake version 3.28.3.
I compiled qwt-6.3.0 from sources with qmake: /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake. I think qt5 is correct here as KDE Plasma 5.27.11 on Kubuntu 24.04 has been built with qt 5.15.13, but I am not sure about this. Is it correct?
The qwt libs are in /usr/local/qwt-6.3.0/lib/ and the headers are in /usr/local/qwt-6.3.0/include/
In CMakeLists.txt
include_directories(/usr/local/qwt-6.3.0/include)
seems to work fine, but I have not been able to use find_package() to find libqwt. What is the correct way to find the qwt lib in CMakeLists.txt?

To use qwt with cmake build you can borrow FindQwt.cmake from QGIS or write one yourself.
Put it into cmake directory on top of source dir and add this path to CMAKE_MODULE_PATH.
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
find_package(Qwt REQUIRED)

qwt build with /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake will not work with Qt 6.7.0, to build qt6 compatible libs you need to use qmake provided with qt6
